# Notice Vs Take Notice Of

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrasal-verbs

I have a question about the verb "*notice*" and verb phrase "*take notice of*":

> 1. He ***noticed*** a stranger in the corner.
> 2. He ***took notice of*** a stranger in the corner.

Are "*notice*" and "*take notice of*" the same?  The dictionaries are not too clear about their difference.

Answer (score 2):

The longer construction "take notice of" is used for emphasis. It implies a conscious effort to notice; that is, paying attention, rather than just passively observing.

Comment: The real question should be what the difference between "take notice of" and "take note of" is.

Answer (score 0):

Of course they are the same. What else meaning we can think of?

> [take notice of](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+notice+of) - ***to notice*** the presence or existence of someone or something

which means it's the same as the verb 'notice'.